# ReSharper wrongly claims that IDictionary.Values is always non null

Tags: c#, resharper, postsharp

I got the following Code:

```
    public IEnumerator<TRow> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (this._rows.Values == null) return Enumerable.Empty<TRow>().GetEnumerator();

        return this._rows.Values.GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Resharper tells me that _rows.Values is always non null (which is not the case because the implementation of IDictionary I use - PostSharps `AdvisableDictionary` from here http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_patterns_collections_advisabledictionary_2) tends to return null right after creation (very awkward implementation i guess - i dont know why they implemented it this way).

[image]

Whatever Implementation of IDictionary I use - Why does ReSharper expect the Implementation to work that way? Nobody can guarantee that this is true. Or did i get something wrong ?

As requested in the Comments: A minimal Implementation that shows the behavior (set a breakpoint on the `return Enumerable.Empty<TRow>().GetEnumerator()` which is grayed out by resharper):

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var model = new Model();

        bool any = model.Any();
    }
}

[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class Model : IEnumerable<string>
{
    private IDictionary<string, string> dictionary;

    public Model()
    {
        dictionary = new AdvisableDictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (dictionary.Values == null) return Enumerable.Empty<string>().GetEnumerator();
        return dictionary.Values.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

this example requires the `PostSharp.Patterns.Model` package and a PostSharp License (there is a trial available) OR swap the `AdvisableDictionary`for a custom dictionary that returns null on the `Values` getter.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: How is `this._rows` defined?

Comment: @DanWilson the minimal implementation i added now does show the declaration of the dictionary.

Comment: You can turn off the Resharper warning for that line of code if you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In newer [referencesource](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/60a4f8b853f60a424e36c7bf60f9b5b5f1973ed1/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/idictionary.cs#L80) Microsoft added some codecontract that covers `IDictionary<,>`:

```
// Returns a collections of the values in this dictionary.
ICollection<TValue> IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Values {
    get {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<ICollection<TValue>>() != null);
        return default(ICollection<TValue>);
    }
}
```

From this contract it is quite clear that `Values` mustn't be `null` (note that it is a `mustn't`, not a `can't` :-) Broken implementations of `IDictionary<,>` can return `null` and it won't be catched by the runtime).

Comment: Thanks for the ref - i will report this to the PostSharp Team. Didn't know there can be contracts on Interface level at all.

Answer (score 1):

It is always `true` because `.Values` always returns something (Collection out of Values). If your Dictionary should be empty, the Values-Collection is also empty. If the dictionary is `null`, there will be a `NullPointerException` since values do not refer to any object.

Comment: That may be true if you use the Dictionary implementation but I use the Dictionary Interface which can have implementations for which this is not true (Which is what I have - and the Implementation is not in my hand).

Comment: @Console Then the implementation of `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` you are using is *broken*. It violates its interface specification, which states that `Values` cannot be null.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I do agree that it is counter intuitive - do you have any sources for the specification that states that? So I can hand it over to Postsharp?

Comment: @Console I'll say that it can't be `null` because there is no explanation for what `null` means in the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yxt5h4s(v=vs.100).aspx) page. Same reason why `IEnumerable<>.GetEnumerator()` can't be `null`.

Comment: @Console the Interface implementation specification is at the microsoft homepage. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea(v=vs.110).aspx)